# How to Retrieve auto incremented ID value to a JLabel

Tags: java, mysql

I have a mysql Database which as Book Id (auto incrementing when I add data) and other rows. I have wrote a code to get the incremented value to a jLabel and it works fine too but still there is a one more little problem. assume I have entered 5 book details. so when I press the Save button (to save the details to database) it saves successfully and `jLabel` shows the incremented value as 6 (so it works fine).

Now the problem is, every time I closed my application and restart it, the jLabel shows the value as 1. Then when I save another book detail it skip to number 7 (which is the correct auto incremented ID). But Why is it showing the ID as 1, when I restart the application? It should read 7 even after I restart it. Here is the code sample. I have even call it in the class Constructor. But it doesn't seem to update. :(

```
private void autoGenerateId() {
    if (true) {
        try {
            ResultSet result = new JDBC().getData("SELECT * FROM newbookstock");
            if (!result.next()) {
                jLabel5.setText("1");
            } else {
                ResultSet result2 = new JDBC().getData("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS bookid FROM newbookstock");
                if (result2.next()) {
                    int id = result2.getInt("bookid") + 1;
                    String ss = String.valueOf(id);
                    jLabel5.setText(ss);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("OOOOO");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Set focus to Jtext1");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's digest your code.

```
        ResultSet result = new JDBC().getData("SELECT * FROM newbookstock");
        if (!result.next()) {
```

This if condition will evaluate to false if the table is empty. So this is not where you are setting the label as 1

```
} else {
                ResultSet result2 = new JDBC().getData("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS bookid FROM newbookstock");
```

Ah, but what do you get here when you first start the program? 0. Why because you have not inserted any values into the table with your current connection.

What you ought to do is

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM newbookstock
```

where you do

```
 SELECT * FROM newbookstoc
```

or perhaps you might want MAX(id) instead of count(*) but select * is definitelly not what you should be using.

and use that value as your initial value. In other news, you have

```
new JDBC().getData(...)
```

in two locations. You shouldn't open multiple connections like this. Open the connection once and reuse it.

update: your snippet to set the initial value might look like:

```
        JDBC conn = new JDBC();
        ResultSet result = jdbc.getData("SELECT COUNT(*) as C FROM newbookstock");
        jLabel5.setText(result2.getString("C"));
```

Comment: MAX(id) is not working and I don't know why. My auto incrementing ID is incrementing from 1 not 0.

Comment: Thank you so much. It really Worked :)

Comment: There is a one problem. 

 try {
            ResultSet result = new JDBC().getData("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM author");
            if (result.next()) {
                String id = result.getString("authorid");
                int v = Integer.parseInt(id);
                int add = v + 1;
                String addition = String.valueOf(add);
                jLabel3.setText(addition);
                System.out.println(addition);
            

This is the new code I wrote for "author" table. But it says "Column 'authorid' not found"

Comment: I have insert the getString appropriate, because it has a column name "authorid". the problem is here the COUNT and the result.next() are two different instances. even if the COUNT is exists, there are no records in the table at first.

Comment: can we forward this discussion with in the chat?

Comment: I have more questions with this code sample.

JDBC conn = new JDBC();
        ResultSet result = jdbc.getData("SELECT COUNT(*) as C FROM newbookstock");
        jLabel5.setText(result2.getString("C"));

I think it should be; 

JDBC conn = new JDBC();
        ResultSet result = conn.getData("SELECT COUNT(*) as C FROM newbookstock");
        jLabel5.setText(result.getString("C"));

right?

Comment: Please help me  :(

Comment: It is COUNT(*) and not COUNT() please refer to the mysql manual for details

Comment: Thank you so much. I really figured it out

Comment: glad to have helped